# Comma separated values to IN function in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to execute below query, but not getting any result.

Could some one tell what wrong I am doing?.

```
DECLARE
  object_types VARCHAR2(200);
  v_object_types VARCHAR2(200);
  l_count number;
BEGIN
  object_types :='TABLE,VIEW';
  select ''''||regexp_replace(object_types, '( )*(,)( )*',''',''')||''''  
         into v_object_types from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(v_object_types));
  SELECT count(*) into l_count
    FROM all_objects o where o.object_type IN ('||v_object_types||');
  dbms_output.put_line(l_count);

END;
```

Comment: what result are you expecting?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: it's returning count as 0, instead of all the table and view count.

Comment: It's looking for a literal string of `'||v_object_types||'`, what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 WHERE variable IN (1,2,3)
```

is different to what you are sending now

```
 WHERE variable IN ('1,2,3')  or
 WHERE variable IN ('||v_object_types||')
```

Comment: it's failing with  IN (v_object_types) also.

Comment: again that is because is a string. You need something like this https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build the SQL dynamically but instead you are using a single string literal `'||v_object_types||'` in the `IN` clause.

You can do it using a collection:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
/
```

**PL/SQL**:

```
DECLARE
  object_types   VARCHAR2(200) := 'TABLE,VIEW';
  v_object_types stringlist;
BEGIN
  SELECT TRIM( BOTH FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR( object_types, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL ) )
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_object_types
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( object_types, '[^,]+' );

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_object_types.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( v_object_types(i) );
  END LOOP;

  SELECT count(*)
  INTO   l_count
  FROM   all_objects
  WHERE  object_type MEMBER OF v_object_types;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_count);
END;
/
```

or using dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE
  object_types   VARCHAR2(200) := 'TABLE,VIEW';
  v_sql          VARCHAR2(200);
  l_count        INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'SELECT count(*) FROM all_objects WHERE  object_type IN ('
             || REGEXP_REPLACE( object_types, ' *(.+?) *(,|$)', '''\1''\2' )
             || ')';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO l_count;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_count);
END;
/
```